# proof verification: the set of irrational numbers is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

I am trying to prove the proposition that

> The set of irrational numbers is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

by using the Baire Category Theorem(referred as BCT from now on)

> Let $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of a complete metric space $X$. Then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ has empty interior.

Let $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of all rational numbers($\cup\{r_n\}=\mathbb{Q}$) in $\mathbb{R}$. Now consider $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $E_n$ is a set of one rational number in $\mathbb{R}$. $E_n=\{r_n\}$ for each $n$. $E_n$ is nowhere dense since $\text{int}(\overline{E_n})=\phi$. $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ has empty interior by BCT.

This implies that for any rational $x$ and for any $r>0$, the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, $B(x;r)$ contains an irrational number. It seems reasonable to conclude that the set of irrational numbers is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I saw some more concise proofs exist such as

> If $t$ is any irrational number and $r$ is a rational, then $\{r+\frac{t}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of irrational numbers that converges to $r$.

Thank you.

Comment: This is very strange. Using BCT for  a very basic fact about the real number system is surely odd. Why don't you just use the 'concise proof' you have seen.

Comment: The proof is correct, though it’s a distinctly odd way to go about proving the fact in question. Should you wish to collect such things, yet another somewhat odd proof is to observe that every open interval in $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so $\Bbb Q$ cannot contain any open interval, and its complement must therefore be dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am studying the book "Introduction to topology" by Gamelin and Greene. This book attemps to construct the real number system by forming the completion of a metric space. Thus the concept of complete metric space is discussed formerly and the real number system is discussed later. I did not saw many applications of BCT, so I just wanted to use it to prove the proposition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. And that's a quite interesting proof.

Comment: @HenryChoi: You’re welcome. (I have to admit that I get a bit of a kick out of easy but odd proofs.)

Comment: minor: did you mix up $a_n$ and $r_n$?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Oh yes I did. Thanks

Comment: One quibble: You need to say something along the lines of $\{r_n\}$ being a sequence of *all* rational numbers, so that $\cup\{r_n\}=\mathbb{Q}$. (I.e., you don't need the countability of the rationals in order justify letting $\{r_n\}$ be a sequence of rationals; you do need it to claim the sequence covers all of $\mathbb{Q}$.) Other than that, this is a delightful proof. Kudos!

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you. I admit that it would be more clear and appropriate to write $\{r_n\}$ is a sequence of all rationals and edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you an easier way way to prove that result.

> A set $B$  is dense in $(X,\tau)$, if every non empty open interval intersects $B$ non-trivially, this is: $\forall U \in \tau, U \cap B \neq \emptyset$.

Let $\mathbb I$ be the set of all irrational numbers. Let's use $\cal B = \{(a,b) \subset \mathbb R\}$ as a basis for $\mathbb R$.

Let $U \in \tau$. Then $U = \bigcup_{j \in J} (a_j,b_j)$, for some index set $J$. Let $i \in J$. We have that between 2 real numbers there is allays an irrational number (You should prove this if you didn't already). So $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb I: \alpha \in (a_i, b_i)$. So $\alpha \in \bigcup_{j \in J} (a_j,b_j) = U$. Thus $\forall U \in \tau, U \cap \mathbb I \neq \emptyset$ concluding that $\mathbb I$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Your definition of "$X$ is dense" is precisely "between 2 real numbers there exists always a number in $X$". So that's really the heart of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

For every real number $a$, just create the irrational sequence $\{a+\frac{e}{n}\} $, then you got your proof simply.

Comment: You are right. But this proof seems different only in notations with the proof that I suggested at the end.

Comment: @HenryChoi notation does not matter. And this seqeuence is only garantueed to be irrational for rational $a$, for irrationals we just take a constant sequence anyway. Why use $e$, when $\sqrt{2}$ will do (and which has a simpler proof of irrationality)?